# How was Becca able to do this in The Boys season 2 finale?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-boys

In the season 2 finale of *The Boys*, Becca pierces a knife into Stormfront's eyes and the latter gets injured very easily. However, in previous episodes Stormfront is capable of withstanding Homelander's lasers. So, it doesn't make sense that Stormfront gets injured that easily with a knife. Was it a mistake or is it that Stormfront is not strong enough (and Homelander was maybe shooting laser with minimum intensity so as to not hurt Stormfront)?

Comment: Eyes are very delicate. Her skin might be impervious but a liquid jelly ball, not so much.

Comment: Choice of convenience to end / botch a finale...

Comment: The eyes were also a weak spot for the [comic version](https://www.cbr.com/the-boys-stormfront-origin-comics-facts/) of Stormfront. - And even though Translucent had (almost?) indestructible skin, his insides were "soft" and seemingly as vulnerable as those of normal humans.

Comment: @Déjàvu - the eyes being a delicate weak-spot is something we see all throughout nature, so complaining that it's somehow a cop-out or a way to "botch" something smacks a bit of complaining for the sake of complaining.  Nothing wrong, illogical or incongruous about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Her body is capable of withstanding Homelander's lasers. We never see anyone attack her eyes. Up until that moment there was no indication that her eyes were more resilient than any normal humans.

Her eyes turned out to be her [Achilles' heel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles%27_heel). Becca had no reason to believe that stabbing Stormfront in the eyes would work, but at that moment it was her only option. She lucked out and it worked. Perhaps Stormfront herself didn't even know (how often is someone stabbed in the eye?).

This kind of weakness in Supes isn't without precedent. In the first season, Translucent was invulnerable in the outside, but his insides were seemingly normal. In Season 2, Black Noir is shown to withstand a lot of abuse, but he has a severe peanut allergy and was very easily put out of commission because of it. Frenchie in particular was very good finding and exploiting weaknesses in Supes which is what got him a spot on Grace Mallory's team.